# R - create sum of particular elements in a vector

Tags: r

Let's say I have a vector

```
v1 <- sample(1:100, 100)
```

and want to obtain the sums over different intervals where the lower and upper indices are defined

```
lower_bound <- c(4,28,56,74)
upper_bound <- c(24,33,86,98)
```

So basically, I want

```
all_sums <- c(sum(v1[4:24]), sum(v1[28:33]), sum(v1[56:86]),sum(v1[74:98]))
```

I could use a loop, but there is certainly a prettier solution. Does anyone have a clue? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `mapply`:

```
mapply(function(i, j) sum(v1[i:j]), lower_bound, upper_bound)
#[1]  962  340 1586 1340

c(sum(v1[4:24]), sum(v1[28:33]), sum(v1[56:86]),sum(v1[74:98]))
#[1]  962  340 1586 1340
```

Data:

```
set.seed(42)
v1 <- sample(1:100, 100)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with mapply function:

`mapply(function(a, b) sum(v1[a:b]), lower_bound, upper_bound)`

Output=>  949  300 1638 1164